# Error: Cask 'java7' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists

Tags: homebrew, homebrew-cask

As one of the projects is using Java 1.7, I wanted the version to run the mrunit test cases manually. I got java8 installed in my machine and also wanted java7.
While I run brew cask install java7, it throws error message - Error: Cask 'java7' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.

As brew cask was suggested in blogs and in Stackoverflow, could you suggest how to install old java version?

```
echo JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

brew cask
Homebrew Cask provides a friendly CLI workflow for the administration
of macOS applications distributed as binaries.

Commands:

    --cache    display the file used to cache the Cask
    audit      verifies installability of Casks
    cat        dump raw source of the given Cask to the standard output
    create     creates the given Cask and opens it in an editor
    doctor     checks for configuration issues
    edit       edits the given Cask
    fetch      downloads remote application files to local cache
    home       opens the homepage of the given Cask
    info       displays information about the given Cask
    install    installs the given Cask

brew cask install java7
Error: Cask 'java7' is unavailable: No Cask with this name exists.
```

References: http://davidcai.github.io/blog/posts/install-multiple-jdk-on-mac/

Comment: Looks like it has been removed from brew-cask: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask-versions/pull/3914

Answer (score -3):

Downloaded the package from Oracle site